# Does EPPlus support MS Office Equations?

Tags: asp.net-core, epplus

I am interested in using EPPlus for generating some xslx report files for a system. I'm interested in whether or not it is possible for EPPlus to tap into Excel's Equation's feature. This is different from formula's. I am aware of EPPlus's ability to add formula's and that's a great feature I am also using. The Equation feature in Excel prints out equations in a nice looking format and I am interested in using that in files I generate with EPPlus.

```
 public ActionResult OnPostDownloadExcelFile()
    {
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        using (var package = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage(ms))
        {
            package.Workbook.Properties.Title = "Excel file with an equation in it";

            // Worksheet
            var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Report");
            worksheet.View.ShowGridLines = true;
            int row = 1;
            int col = 1;

            worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value = "I want to put an equation here...";
        }

        return File(ms, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "ExcelFileExample.xlsx");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not supported in EPPlus. Equations are an embedded object. Embedded objects are not presently supported: https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/wiki/FAQ#what-is-not-supported-by-the-library-these-are-the-most-obvious-features

Comment: Any idea if there is any way to do this at all? Like with the MSFT C# Interop library?

Comment: Here's a way to do it using Interop:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17860447/embed-object-in-excel-programmatically

And FYI the class name you're looking for should be "Equation.3"

Comment: I believe this is now supported by eeplus, see this page for supported functions https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/wiki/Supported-Functions

Comment: I believe the link @seabass77 provided is to the support for formulas. OP is looking for information about embedding an OLE object representing the MS Equations object.

Comment: @JohnTesmer Yes you are correct, my bad. I'd like to leave them comment though, since it could be an alternatively method to using MS office functions.